# Convert sql to linq where incoming date and time . Need to add time HH

Tags: sql, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

This is the SQL Server sql statement that passed in the date and time (24 hour time)

```
declare @date varchar(10) = '2-15-2017'
declare @time varchar(2) = '11'
declare @timeExt varchar(3) = ':00'


--declare @mytime datetime = '2-15-2017 11:00'
declare @mytime datetime = @date + ' ' + @time + @timeExt

select * from [dbo].[QAList] Q
where q.CreatedDateTime between dateadd(hh,-1, @mytime) and @mytime
```

**Then for Linq to SQL ( Entities)  I was doing only Date , but i need to add in the time**

```
string dateIn = "2-15-2017";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(dateIn);
```

Notice the `.Where`

```
   var query =  QALists
    .Where (z => z.CreatedDateTime >= d )
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(z => new QAList()
                {
                    Agent = z.Agent,
                    ClientName = z.ClientName,
                    Disposition = z.Disposition,
                    CallDate = z.Calldate,
                    Comment = z.Comment,
                    CreatedDateTime = z.CreatedDateTime,
                    CallLength = z.CallLength,
                    IdentityColumnId = z.IdentityColumnId,
                    Number = z.Number,
                    InboundCall = z.InboundCall,
                    OutboundCall = z.OutboundCall,
                    Status = z.Status,
                    QAListId = z.QAListId     
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing LINQ specific in the question - just create two `DateTime` variables containing the desired range (as you know, `DateTime` data type contains both date and time):

```
var endTime = new DateTime(2017, 02, 15, 11, 00, 00);
var startTime = endTime.AddHours(-1);
```

then simply use them in the query criteria:

```
.Where (z => z.CreatedDateTime >= startTime && z.CreatedDateTime <= endTime)
```